# Touch Control Support for AIR_FRESHENER Device Type?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I am hoping to build a Google Smart Home Action that will integrate with our IoT device.

After [reading the documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/touch-controls#supported_device_types_2) though, I am seeing that air fresheners do not support touch controls.

This is an important feature we would like to provide to our customers, and I want to find the best route to request support for this device type.

Does anyone have suggestions on where to go first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are working on providing touch controls for an extended set of devices at the moment. You can make the request to add controls for new device types such as the AIR_FRESHNER through the public issue [tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148). This will greatly help us to prioritize the device types and prepare the roadmap for our ecosystem.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your helpful response. I attempted to use the issue tracker you linked but was met with a google.com login page. Can you help me get access to submit an issue?